# Stop Angular Animation from happening on ng-show / ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, animation, font-awesome, angularjs-animation

In my AngularJS application I'm using fontawesome for my loading spinners:

```
<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" ng-show="loading"></i>
```

I'm also using AngularToaster for notification messages which has a dependency on ngAnimate.  When I include ngAnimate in my AngularJS application, it messes up my loading spinners by animating them in a weird way.  I want to stop this from happening but cant find a way to disable the animation on just these loaders (it would also stink to have to update every loader I have in my app).

Heres a plunkr showing my exact problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wVY5iSpUST52noIA2h5a

Comment: I came across this answer, but I'd rather not decorate all of my loaders with a "no-animate" directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879654/angularjs-exclude-certain-elements-from-animations?rq=1

Comment: What about creating your own show directive?

Comment: @lucuma I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if I could avoid it.  Plus that also involves me updating all my loaders with this new ng-show directive. My ideal solution would be to configure it in one place and forget about it.

Comment: This exposes one of the issues with automatic animation in 1.2.  I keep hoping they'll go back to the declarative way they had in 1.1.  I don't think angular should animate elements unless I specifically tell them what to animate.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat, because Angular is so modular it isn't so much an issue but just keeping up with the changes.  I didn't know until I just researched it about the classNameFilter which gives you a lot of control over what is animated.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use the `$animateProvider.classNameFilter` which will allow you to filter items to animate or in this case not to animate.  We'll do something like:

```
 $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/^((?!(fa-spinner)).)*$/);
 //$animateProvider.classNameFilter(/^((?!(fa-spinner|class2|class3)).)*$/);
```

Demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lbqviQ87MQoZWeXplax1?p=preview

Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$animateProvider) state:

> Sets and/or returns the CSS class regular expression that is checked
>   when performing an animation. Upon bootstrap the classNameFilter value
>   is not set at all and will therefore enable $animate to attempt to
>   perform an animation on any element. When setting the classNameFilter
>   value, animations will only be performed on elements that successfully
>   match the filter expression. This in turn can boost performance for
>   low-powered devices as well as applications containing a lot of
>   structural operations.

As another answer per the comment with the `no-animate` directive, you could write an `ng-show` directive that will run at a higher priority and disable the animation.  We will only do this if the element has the `fa-spinner` class.

```
  problemApp.directive('ngShow', function($compile, $animate) {
    return {
      priority: 1000,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        if (element.hasClass('fa-spinner')) {
          // we could add no-animate and $compile per 
          // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879654/angularjs-exclude-certain-elements-from-animations?rq=1
          // or we can just include that no-animate directive's code here
          $animate.enabled(false, element)
          scope.$watch(function() {
            $animate.enabled(false, element)
          })

        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/BYrhEompZAF5RKxU7ifJ?p=preview

Lastly, and similar to the above, we can use the `no-animate` directive if we want to make it a little more modular.  In this case I'm naming the directive `faSpin` which you could do in the answer above.  This is essentially the same only we are preserving the directive from the SO answer mentioned in the comment of the above codeset.  If you only care about the `fa-spin` animation issues naming it this way works well, but if you have other `ng-show` animation problems you'd want to name it `ngShow` and add to the if clause.

```
  problemApp.directive('noAnimate', ['$animate',
    function($animate) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          $animate.enabled(false, element)
          scope.$watch(function() {
            $animate.enabled(false, element)
          })
        }
      };
    }
  ])

  problemApp.directive('faSpin', function($compile, $animate) {
    return {
      priority: 1000,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        if (element.hasClass('fa-spinner')) {
          element.attr('no-animate', true);
          $compile(element)(scope);

        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/P3R74mUR27QUyxMFcyf4?p=preview

Comment: No problem.  Out of curiosity which solution are you going to use?

Comment: Definitely the $animateProvider solution.  I can do it in one place and have it effect my whole application. Thanks so much for providing multiple solutions though.  It helps me understand a couple different places I can hook into in AngularJS that I never thought of.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I used $animateProvider with fa-spin instad of fa-spinner

Comment: I do not understand your no-animate directive: what are you watching for? The function in first parameter of scope.watch should return the watch value, yes?

Comment: The second directive which by the way was a copy/paste from Angular's no-animate directive will fire anytime there is a DOM change I believe.

Comment: Thanks @lucuma!! I used $animateProvider with fa-spin instad of fa-spinner solution too. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

I had a similar problem where my icon would keep spinning until the animation finished, even after the $scope variable turned off. What worked for me was to wrap the `<i>` fa-icon element in a span.

```
<span ng-if="loading"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></span>
```

Try it!

Comment: Simple and easy... just place a <span> around the element you animate and apply the ng-if there.

Comment: Why bother adding JS when you can place a simple span around the element you want to hide/show. I think this is definitely what angular tries to achieve.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - no need to use a directive or some other JavaScript code. Simple and effective

Comment: This worked for me.  In my case the <i> is already wrapped in a <div> that is hidden/shown based on a boolean.  The issue I was seeing is when someone would click the button it would show this icon and start to spin, but would stop spinning after a second or so.  Wrapping the <i> in a <span> solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I've found an easier way.

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner" ng-show="loading" ng-class="{'fa-spin' : loading}"></i>
```

Forked plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mCsw5wBL1bsLYB7dCtQF

I did run into another small issue as a result of doing this where the icon would appear out of position if it spun for more than 2 seconds, but that was caused by the 'ng-hide-add-active' class, so I just added in my css:

```
.fa-spinner.ng-hide-add-active {
    display: none !important;
}
```

and that took care of it.

EDIT: Nico's solution is a slightly cleaner version of this, so I'd consider using his.

Comment: that css worked for me like a charm. this is truly the best fix for the problem.

Comment: This is great, but the problem here is, you'll need to add the ng-class directive to every one of your loader elements.  It fixes the problem, but if you have a lot of spinners throughout your application, it could get messy updating them all.

Comment: @ChrisLees true- I didn't even think about that, but that's because we created a spinner directive that encapsulated this and then just used that one spinner everywhere. Honestly, I like nicotr014's answer better now anyways- it's really just a spin-off of this answer.

Comment: @JamesFiala I do like the idea of creating a spinner directive to use everywhere.  Staying consistent with variable names this could be pretty handy to have.

Comment: @ChrisLees You dont need to update ng-class. Instead, you can have `fa-spin` inside the class instead of ng-class.  `<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="loading">`

Answer (score 3):

```
angular.module('myCoolAppThatIsAwesomeAndGreat')
  .config(function($animateProvider) {

    // ignore animations for any element with class `ng-animate-disabled`
    $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/^((?!(ng-animate-disabled)).)*$/);

  });
```

Then you can just add the class `ng-animate-disabled` to any element you want.

`<button><i class="fa fa-spinner ng-animate-disabled" ng-show="somethingTrue"></i></button>`

Answer (score 0):

Updating [James Fiala Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756429/1154350).

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="loading"></i>
```

You don't need the `ng-class` as mentioned in [@James Fiala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/899072/james-fiala)  Answer. But you should have `fa-spin` as one of the class.

#### Add style

```
.fa-spinner.ng-hide-add-active {
   display: none !important;
}
```